# Fortran user defined operators precedence rules

Tags: fortran, operators, operator-precedence

The built-in operators of Fortran have well-defined precedence rules. What about user-defined operators? I understand that user-defined binary operators have a lower priority than every built-in operator, as explicitly indicated [here](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/fortran-compiler-oneapi-dev-guide-and-reference/top/language-reference/expressions-and-assignment-statements/expressions/summary-of-operator-precedence.html). Is it possible to modify such behavior? And is it possible to establish user-defined precedence between user-defined operators? Or do we have only the wise use of parentheses to control the order of operations?

Comment: You know "that user-defined binary operators have a lower priority than every built-in operator" as defined by the standard, so can you say why you know that? (How you understand the origin of the rule determines how we explain the fact you can't change that.)

Comment: Although it is clear what you mean, can you show a small snippet of code with user-defined operations so that answers can use a consistent terminology?

Comment: @francescalus I think that an example should not be necessary for such a general question. However, if you like a specific example, let's assume that an operator ".x." has been defined to evaluate the vector product between two 3D vectors represented as a 3-component rank-1 array. If you have an expression like  "L + a .x.b" my experience with gfortran is that the "+" operator has precedence wrt ".x.". Such behavior is consistent with the precedence I found in the Intel page linked in my edited quesiton.

Comment: An example is not necessary, no. But if one answer talks about operators A, B and C and another about X, Y and Z we make it harder for people reading the question and answers in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I explain ALL of this in https://stevelionel.com/drfortran/2021/04/03/doctor-fortran-in-order-order/

Briefly, user-defined unary (one operand) operators have the highest precedence, user-defined binary operators (two operands) have the lowest precedence. You cannot adjust operator precedence.

Comment: Clear and enlightening answer. It leaves me just a final doubt: if I understand well, the precedence is a consequence of the "nesting rules" for expressions. Therefore, while a user-defined binary operator has the lowest priority, an overloaded existing operator keeps its priority even if used in the presence of user-defined data types. Is it a correct guess?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Precedence is a syntax thing, so an overloaded intrinsic operator keeps its precedence. I recall that SNOBOL4 defined some operators that were unused in the language, with various precedence and association, that you could use for your own operations.